# Looping through Array in multiple <td> cells

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

Lets say I have an array

```
$aSomeArray = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
```

Now displaying one array value in one table row is easy like this

```
echo "<table>";

foreach ($aSomeArray as $iSomeArrayKey => $iSomeArrayValue)
{   
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>".$iSomeArrayValue."</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

But I want to display the values in table format like this

```
1    2    3    4
5    6    7    8
9    10   11   12
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: how will you determine at what index the iteration over the array stops ? does it follow any patter in general ?

Comment: Not any specific pattern, I just want to get the data displayed in multiple td's rather than one row at a time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edited, this works:

```
$aSomeArray = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
$i = 0;
echo "<table>\r\n";
foreach ($aSomeArray as $aSomeArrayKey => $aSomeArrayValue)
{   
    if (($i % 4) == 0) echo "\t<tr>\r\n";
    echo "\t\t<td>" . $aSomeArrayValue . "</td>\r\n";
    if (($i % 4) == 3) echo "\t</tr>\r\n";
    $i++;
}
echo "</table>\r\n";
```

Comment: What is the problem with it? Do you get an error? Or what's the returned output? Are you sure you wrote it correctly?

Comment: Ooops. Sorry. I tested it, changed it and this time it works. Also added some tabs and linebreaks so that's it looks better in "view-source".

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought which seems nicer IMHO.

```
<?php
$aSomeArray = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");

function createMatrix($width, $array)
{
 $newArray = array();
 $temp = array();
 $count = 1;

 foreach($array as $key => $value)
 {
  $temp[] = $value;

  if(($count++ % $width) == 0)
  {
   $newArray[] = $temp;
   $temp = array();
  }
 }
 if( count($temp) > 0)
 {
  $newArray[] = $temp;
 }
 return $newArray;
}
```

will create a matrix array of variable `$width`
You can then use that data as a double for-each like this:

```
$matrix = createMatrix(2, $aSomeArray );

foreach($matrix as $row)
{
 echo "<tr>\n";
 foreach($row as $td)
 {
  echo "\t<td>{$td}</td>\n";
 }
 echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Which produces:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do a running count. So before the foreach set `$i = 1` and every fourth result, reset the count to `$i = 1` and then end the row and re-open a new row.

Answer (score 1):

```
$aSomeArray = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13");

$columns = 4; // The number of columns to shown

echo "<table>";

$i = 0;
$trOpen = false; // just a flag if <tr> has been closed (paired with </tr>) or not.
foreach ($aSomeArray as $item) {
    if ($i % $columns == 0) {
        echo "<tr>";
        $trOpen = true;
    }

    echo "<td>" . $item . "</td>";

    if (($i + 1) % $columns == 0) {
        echo "</tr>";
        $trOpen = false;
    }

    $i++;
}

if ($trOpen) {
    echo "</tr>"; // add '</tr>' if it is not yet added.
}

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($aSomeArray as $aSomeArrayKey => $aSomeArrayValue)
{   
 echo "<td>".$aSomeArrayValue."</td>";
 if($aSomeArrayValue % 4 == 0)
     echo "</tr><tr>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=1;
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($aSomeArray as $aSomeArrayKey => $aSomeArrayValue)
{   

     echo "<td>".$aSomeArrayValue."</td>";
     $i++;
     if($i%4==0){
         echo "<tr></tr>";
     }
}
echo "</tr>";
```

It will also work for the indivisible by 4 number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
$i=0;
echo"<table>";
echo"<tr>";
foreach($aSomeArrayas as $val)
{
if($i %4 ==0)
  {
     echo"</tr><tr> <td> $val</td>";  
  }
  else
  {
    echo"<td> $val </td>";  
  }
  $i++;
}
echo"</tr>";
echo"</table>";
?>
```